# Make environment variables available for all script and programming language

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I've some variables used by GO, Node, and PHP applications on the same server. I'm trying to put all the variables into the system and make them available for all applications.

but I tried to put the variable in ~/.profile, etc/profile and /etc/environment and I can access them tough terminal or If run the script from the terminal but if try to run using supervisor, like go app using supervisor and from a PHP script that runs by nginx server, it seems the script can't find the variable.

Am I missing something or is there a better way for that?

Answer (score 2):

**1. Profile and non-interactive use**

`profile`-files are being loaded only for interactive shells/environments and thus not if a command is run non-interactively, e.g. by `nginx` in the background. The only way for a system-wide variable would thus be `/etc/environment`, however:

**2. `nginx`-specific issues**

`nginx` actually kills all environment variables. [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env)

> By default, nginx removes all environment variables inherited from its parent process except the TZ variable.

In your `nginx`-config, use `env variable=value;` to redefine or `env variable` to inherit it from the system.

**3. `supervisor`-specific issues**

From [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47219590/5114441): Environment variables are inherited from the shell that runs it, if there never was one, you will have to define them.

Add `EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment` to the `systemd` service file of `supervisor`. I assume you run it like that?